# how can i solve this laravel project installation problem?

Tags: laravel

When I try to install a new project in my `htdocs` folder in that time i get this error:

> [Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException] Invalid repository
>   data in C:\xampp\htdocs/vendor/composer/installed.json, packages could
>   not be loaded: [Seld\Json Lint\ParsingException]
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs/vendor/composer/installed.json" does not contain
>   valid JSON Parse error on line 1:
>
> \\\\\\\\\\ ^ Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL',
>   'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

My installation command is:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel CruiseBag "5.6.*"
```

Comment: Maybe try to clear the composer cache? `composer clear-cache` or, if you installed it this way https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#installing-laravel you can run `laravel new CruiseBag`

Comment: if i use this command it will installed laravel version 6 but i need 5.6 version...

Comment: You can use any version of laravel via composer example : ```composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel {your-project-name} "5.6.*"```

Comment: i know that but when i use this command its give me an error..that the reason i posted here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install Laravel on Windows**

1. Download Composer’s Windows .exe installer:
   https://getcomposer.org/download/
2. Run the installer
3. Open Window’s CMD or PowerShell

   cd C:\xampp\htdocs
4. Install Laravel using Composer

   composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel CruiseBag "5.6"

[See](https://www.webhostface.com/kb/knowledgebase/install-laravel-windows/)

Comment: there was an extra vendor folder in my htdocs folder that the reason i got this error..delete this folder and follow your suggestion...its work fine..

Answer (score 1):

```
// first composer download, then composer install
// Or command use: 
composer global require "laravel/installer"

 //then 
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.6.*"
```